# Broadcast receiver with no handlers (best practice)

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have 2 separate applications appA and appB.

if both app are not present on phone no problems here :).

if both present again no problems here, because appA sends a broadcast and appB it handles that broadcast.

The interesting scenario is when appA is present but appB is not present.

-Should appA send a broadcast anyway

or

-appA should check if appB is present and send the broadcast only if appB is present.

Note:appA doesn't need any feedback if someone handles the broadcast or not...

But what is the right way to do this?

What happens in general when broadcast is send and no one handles that broadcast ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's nothing to handle the broadcast, nothing happens. Since you don't care about whether it was handled, it should be sufficient just to broadcast it without checking.